# Unity OnMouseDown does nothing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an RTS game and I need to display tower's statistics when player clicks it.

But OnMouseDown does nothing.
Can you tell what problems can i have?

And yes my towers have colliders(MeshCollider)
And also the script is attached too

The code I tried:

```
public void OnMouseDown(){
    Debug.Log("clicked")
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: make sure that your object is on a layer that allows raycasts and that your object is not obstructed by other colliders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced mesh collider to box collider and now it works!
My mesh collider was too big. i don't know why

Comment: I think it won't work if the mesh collider is not convex